# Parameterizing a json for jmeter test

Tags: json, parameters, jmeter

I am running a HTTP request test in jmeter where I send a json input. For example:
{
 "attribute1":"lala"
 "attribute2":"lala"
}

I need to parametrize this so that for each thread iteration a different value for attribute1 and attribute2 is chosen, possibly from a csv or text file.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it is possible!!

**Add CSV Data Set Config**

[image]

**Update your file path**

[image]

**Parameterize with CSV column name**

Update the column names in your JSON to parameterize.

if attr1 is the column 1 - then use ${attr1} to get the value from the CSV

[image]

**Correction:**

The json in abobe image should be

```
{
    "attribute1":"${attr1}",
    "attribute2":"${attr2}"
}
```

Comment: shouldn't attr1 stay as it is and lala changes to ${attr1} and ${attr2} ?